Nan value when using nn.Dropout() in AlexNet on CIFAR-10 implementing Per-FedAvg algorithm
I'm implementing the Per-FedAvg algorithm with HF-MAML, in which the Hessian Matrix product is approximated by disturbing model parameters $W$ with a small delta $\delta$ (e.g. 0.001), and is calculated as bellow:
$H = \frac{\nabla (w+\delta*\nabla w)-\nabla (w-\delta*\nabla w)}{2*\delta}$
Then we use the following formula to update model:
$w' = w - \beta \times ( \nabla w * (I- \alpha * H))$
Where \alpha and \beta are predefined learning-rate-like parameters. I is the identity matrix so the upper equation can be written in python code:
for param, grad1, grad2 in zip(model.parameters(), grad_1, grad_2):
    param.data.sub_(beta * grad1 - beta * alpha * grad2)

After updating the local models, they are sent to server for averaging.
However, when I use AlexNet on CIFAR-10 dataset, the training loss will suddenly explode to Nan at some point. I tried a lot of methods, and the only way to deal with it is to comment the nn.Dropout() functions in model.
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            # nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(256 * 2 * 2, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            # nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 512),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, class_num),
        )

I just don't understand why. The full model code and the training code are as follows.
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,class_num=10):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            # 3 32 32
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            # 64 32+2-2=32 32/2=16
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            # 64 16 16
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
            # 64 8 8
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            # 192 8 8
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
            # 192 4 4
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            # 384 4 4
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            # 256 4 4
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
            # 256 2 2
        )
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            # nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(256 * 2 * 2, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            # nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 512),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, class_num),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 256 * 2 * 2)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        # return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x

def train(model, train_loader, alpha, beta, local_iters=None, local_epochs=1, device=torch.device("cpu"), model_type=None):
    t_start = time.time()
    model.train()
    
    # First Order MAML train for local_ites
    if local_iters is None:
        # 2 batches 1 update
        local_iters = math.ceil(len(train_loader.loader.dataset) / train_loader.loader.batch_size / 2)
    
    losses = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    sample_num = [0, 0, 0]

    for epoch_idx in range(local_epochs):
        for epoch in range(local_iters):
            temp_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
            # step 1: one step train
            batch_1 = next(train_loader)
            temp_model, one_step_loss = one_step(device, batch_1, temp_model, model_type, lr=alpha)

            # step 2: get grad
            batch_2 = next(train_loader)
            grad_1, grad_loss = compute_grad(temp_model, batch_2, device)

            # step 3: approximate 2nd grad
            batch_3 = next(train_loader)
            grad_2, grad2_loss = compute_grad(model, batch_3, device, v=grad_1, second_order_grads=True)

            # step 3: update model
            for param, grad1, grad2 in zip(model.parameters(), grad_1, grad_2):
                param.data.sub_(beta * grad1 - beta * alpha * grad2)
        
            losses = [losses[0]+one_step_loss, losses[1]+grad_loss, losses[2]+grad2_loss]
            sample_num = [sample_num[0]+len(batch_1[0]), sample_num[1]+len(batch_2[0]), sample_num[2]+len(batch_3[0])]

    return {'train_loss': losses[0]/sample_num[0] if sample_num[0] != 0 else losses[0], 
            'grad_loss': losses[1]/sample_num[1] if sample_num[1] != 0 else losses[1], 
            'grad2_loss': losses[2]/sample_num[2] if sample_num[2] != 0 else losses[2],
            'train_time': time.time()-t_start,
            'samples_num': sum(sample_num),
            'params': torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(model.parameters()).detach()}


def one_step(device, data, model, model_type, lr):
    """
    Performs one step of training for a given device, data, model, and learning rate.

    Args:
        device (torch.device): The device (CPU or GPU) on which to perform the calculations.
        data (tuple): A tuple containing the input sequence (seq) and corresponding label (label).
        model (torch.nn.Module): The model to train.
        lr (float): The learning rate for the optimizer.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing the updated model and the loss value as a float.
    """
    seq, label = data

    if model_type == 'LR':
        seq = data.squeeze(1).view(-1, 28 * 28)

    seq = seq.to(device)
    label = label.to(device)
    y_pred = model(seq)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
    loss = loss_function(y_pred, label)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    return model, loss.item()


def compute_grad(model, data_batch, device, v=None, second_order_grads=False):
    """
    Compute the gradients of the model parameters with respect to the loss function.

    Parameters:
    - model: The model for which to compute the gradients.
    - data_batch: The input data batch consisting of features and labels.
    - device: The device on which to perform the computations.
    - v: Optional. The second-order gradients used for computation.
    - second_order_grads: Optional. Whether to compute second-order gradients.

    Returns:
    - grads: The gradients of the model parameters.
    - loss: The computed loss value.
    """
    x, y = data_batch
    x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)

    if second_order_grads:
        frz_model_params = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
        delta = 1e-3
        dummy_model_params_1 = OrderedDict()
        dummy_model_params_2 = OrderedDict()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for (layer_name, param), grad in zip(model.named_parameters(), v):
                dummy_model_params_1.update({layer_name: param + delta * grad})
                dummy_model_params_2.update({layer_name: param - delta * grad})

        model.load_state_dict(dummy_model_params_1, strict=False)
        logit_1 = model(x)
        # loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
        loss_1 = loss_func(logit_1, y)

        grads_1 = torch.autograd.grad(loss_1, model.parameters())

        model.load_state_dict(dummy_model_params_2, strict=False)
        logit_2 = model(x)
        # loss_func_2 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss_2 = loss_func(logit_2, y)
        grads_2 = torch.autograd.grad(loss_2, model.parameters())

        model.load_state_dict(frz_model_params)

        grads = []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for g1, g2 in zip(grads_1, grads_2):
                grads.append((g1 - g2) / (2 * delta))
        return grads, (loss_1.item()+loss_2.item())/2

    else:
        logit = model(x)
        loss = loss_func(logit, y)
        grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, model.parameters())
        return grads, loss.item()

I tried the following:

lower the learning rate, i.e. Alpha and beta. Didn't help. Some clients' model will suddenly jump to a infinite training loss, then updating these models to server will cause all models to degrade to a mess.

lower the disturbing parameter \delta. It becomes even worse, as in the first round all models get a Nan test loss. I believe this could be the place where the issue hides.

Disable the two Dropout() layer in AlexNet. It worked, and runs smoothly towards the end.


I believe the Dropout somehow break my training process, but disabling it may overfit the model. If I can figure out the real issue then I can use Dropout without concerns.
